# How can override application-default.yml values in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

Assume there are three separate spring boot projects that depend on each other like this:

Other-App ----> My-Library ----> Other-Library

The Other-Library has a property that is mandatory and fills by spring boot configuration properties.
The Other-App optionally uses My-Library(and Other-library).
The My-library is my own code that I can manipulate it(other modules are out of my hand).

The problem is if the Other-App does not set the property of the Other-Library, It faced an application startup exception. The Other-App does not use the My-library(and Other-library) necessary, so maybe it does not set all mandatory properties of all dependencies.

I created an application-default.yml in the My-Library to set the default value of the Other-library property. but now the Other-App only with an application-default.yml can override my default value if it wants to use its dependency.

Is there any way to set the default value for other module properties?
Or is there a better way to override application-default.yml in the eventual user?

Comment: Use `@ConfigurationProperties` and just give the field a default value like a normal Java class.

Comment: The property already defined by `@ConfigurationProperties` but as I said it defined in Other-Library and I don't have access to it.